# Can't manipulate Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using MVC, have standard scaffolded index.cshtml page. 
My goal is to display the details on a modal box. I'm able to display the modal box however whatever I do the modal is always and always displayed on the top left side of the screen. I'm trying to manipulate it using css but it fails whatever I do it does not work

so what I have done is:

**Index.cshtml**

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal TestModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog TestModal">
        <div class="modal-content TestModal">
            <div id="myModalContent" class="TestModal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1- Created a partialView

```
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Validation Error</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p class="text-warning">
        <small>Please make an entry before save</small>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
</div>
```

2-Created the following method in my controller

```
public PartialViewResult DisplayModalFor(int id)
    {
        //var parent = _context.TOURNAMENTS_M.Include(x => x.TOURNAMENTS_D).First(x => x.TM_ROWID.Equals(Id));
        return PartialView("_DetailsModal");
    }
```

and finally I have the following function in my javascript file:

```
function PopUpModalFor(tmRowid) {

const id = tmRowid;
$.ajax({
    url: "/TOURNAMENTS_M/DisplayModalFor",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            id: id
        }
    })
    .done(function (result) {

        $("#myModalContent").html(result);
        $("#myModal").modal("show");

    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("I failed :'( ");
    });
```

}

thoughts?

[image]

I have a weird problem here! 
though I have included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/MyStyle.css" />
```

into my _Layout.cshtml, my CSS is not working completely.

for example I have

```
.YOLO {
background-color: green;
}

.Padded {

    margin: 50px 100px 0 100px !important;
}
```

then I have modified my index.cshtml to look like this

```
<div class="Padded">
   <p class="YOLO">THIS SHOULD BE GREEN</p>
   <h2>Index</h2>
//More code..
```

however the p tag is not green what should I do?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of what you have and what you want?

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: Where's your css code? Also make sure you are actually loading your css and make sure you are loading it after your bootstrap css.

Comment: I have posted css. too something weird is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [here](https://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc). But don't know whether it is working for you or not. Can you just try below? Anyway, by default, it should align into the middle.

```
#myModal{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.modal:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```